# Updating mysql table using Php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm selecting some data from a table `pre_product`,
then i show them to the user so he pick some row and fill some boxes,
then i go to update `pre_product` and insert a new data into another table

```
`anodization`
```

[image]

the problem is, after submitting the updated data is changing to be `0.00000` 
not the value that i want it to be.
here's my code briefly

```
<?php
$pp_select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pre_product
WHERE pre_product_status != 'anodized'
AND pre_product_status != 'packed'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($pp_select))
    {
        $pp_id[$loop] = $row['pre_product_number'];
        $pp_date[$loop] = $row['pre_product_date'];
        $pp_available[$loop] = $row['pre_product_anodization_availabe'];


        if($submit[$loop])
        {
                /*PRE-PRODUCT DATABASE*/
                $available_update[$loop] = $pp_available[$loop] - $weight[$loop];
                //Check if pp is fully anodized
                if($available_update[$loop] == 0)
                    $pp_new_status[$loop] = "anodized";
                else $pp_new_status[$loop] = "semi-anodized";
                $update_pp = mysql_query("UPDATE pre_product
                                                  SET pre_product_anodization_availabe = '$available_update[$loop]'
                                                  AND pre_product_status = '$pp_new_status[$loop]'
                                                  WHERE pre_product_number = '$pp_id[$loop]'
                                                  AND pre_product_date = '$pp_date[$loop]'");

            }
        $loop++;
        }
```

the problem again , after submitting the value of `pre_product_anodization_availabe` is changing to 0.00000

Comment: What is the value of `$available_update[$loop]` in this example? and what is the `type` of the field in question?

Comment: $available update[$loop] should be the result of  $pp_available[$loop](db_record) - $weight[$loop](user_input) , its type is float(5,5)

Comment: Stop using PHP's deprecated mysql _ API

Comment: Also miss-spelling words like "availabe" is likely to lead to confusion/error

Answer (score 0):

You're value is being changed to 0.00000 because you are using the float datatype(5,5) where the second number is the amount of decimal places.

Check out [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html) resource, specifically this:

> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE
>   PRECISION(M,D). Here, (M,D) means than values can be stored with up to
>   M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point.
>   For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999
>   when displayed. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you
>   insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is
>   999.0001.

Comment: its expected to see another numbers not zeros , this should be an output of a mathematical operation , what happens that he gives me zeros whatever the real result is and that's my problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. Can you confirm the value $available_update[$loop]? Are you certain the value is non-zero in php?